# Replacing Everything Except specific pattern BigQuery

Tags: regex, string, replace, google-bigquery

I would like to use regex to replace everything (except a specific pattern) with empty string in BigQuery. I have following values:

```
AX/88/8888888
AX/99/999999
AX/11/222222 - AX/22/33333 - AX/999/99999
BX/99/9999
1234455121
AX/00/888888 // BX/890/90890
NULL
[XYZ-ASA
BX/890/90890 + AX/10/1010101
AX/99/9999M
AX/111/111,AX-99
AX/11/222222 BX/99/99 AX/22/33333
```

The pattern will always have "AX" in the beginning, then a slash (/) and some numbers and slash(/) again and some numbers after it. (The pattern would always be `AX/\d+/\d+`)

I would like to replace anything (any character,brackets,digit etc) that doesn't follow that pattern mention above.

For the cases where the pattern doesn't match at all for example (BX/99/9999,1234455121, NULL,[XYZ-ASA) are the only cases from the above dataset.

** doesn't match at all means cases where the entire values doesn't have any value
that matches with the AX/\d+/\d+. In those situations, I would like to return then original text as final output.

The case where we have matching pattern for example AX/00/888888 // BX/890/90890, AX/111/111,AX-99 the pattern matches but the latter part needs to be replaced i.e [// BX/890/90890] and [,AX-99] , which should then return only the AX/00/888888, and AX/111/111 as final output.

The expected output from the above example is following:

```
AX/88/8888888
AX/99/999999
AX/11/222222 AX/22/33333 AX/999/99999
BX/99/9999
1234455121
AX/00/888888 
NULL
[XYZ-ASA
AX/10/1010101
AX/99/9999
AX/111/111
AX/11/222222 AX/22/33333
```

Later I would like to split all the values by space, to get each AX/xx/xx on a different row where I have multiple of those for example case 3 from above would produce 3 rows.

```
AX/88/8888888
AX/99/999999
AX/11/222222 
AX/22/33333 
AX/999/99999
BX/99/9999
1234455121
AX/00/888888 
NULL
[XYZ-ASA
AX/10/1010101
AX/99/9999
AX/111/111
AX/11/222222
AX/22/33333
```

Comment: Can you clarify - what is the difference between `doesn't follow that pattern` and `pattern doesn't match at all`?? looks like your what to treat those two cases differently and this is confusing. please clarify

Comment: Can you also clarify why `BX/99/9999` would be included in your final output since it partially matched the pattern (a slash (/) and some numbers and slash(/) again and some numbers after it) and only violates your rule where "the pattern will always have "AX" in the beginning".

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant they are essentially the same thing. I have added some more description. Essentially, the cases where we have nothing that matches the pattern AX/\d+/\d+, should return the original text. But if a value matches in a row, then we need to keep only the texts that matches the pattern and replace anything that doesn't with empty character.

Comment: @ScottB BX/99/999 is in the final output as I mentioned that cases where the pattern doesn't match AX/\d+/\d+. I would like to return the original text i.e BX/99/9999. I have added more description and examples above

Comment: i think it makes sense now, looking further :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant glad to clarify

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant the end goal is to then split all the data where we have multiple AX/**** values to separate rows. For example the third case i.e `AX/11/222222 AX/22/33333 AX/999/99999` . While for the others we will have one row, where it doesn't match or where we only have one single AX/*** matching value

Comment: sure, that part was clear from the very beginning :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant perfect :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
select coalesce(result, col) as col 
from your_table
left join unnest(regexp_extract_all(col, r'AX/\d+/\d+')) result
```

if applied to sample data in your question

[image]

output is

[image]

Comment: I believe the solution runs perfectly, i will do some testing. I have one questions, the regex_extract_all returns an array and the unnest splits it. It creates an array where it doesn't match the pattern and otherwise returns null. One question, what's the purpose of left join here ? I can see my rows reduces if i remove the left join from your code. Can you explain that :)

Comment: @Mikail there is one small issue, sometimes there are duplicate values, how can i make the array take distinct values for example `AX/88/8888888 - AX/88/8888888M` would just return AX/88/8888888

Comment: just add distinct to select statement

Comment: can you also please tell why there is a need of a left join ? if we just do simple unnest, why will it not work ?

Comment: sure. in cases when you unnest empty array and want to preserve original row  - you should use left join, otherwise - you can simply use cross join (which is represented by comma) or join .  to see this  - try `with your_table as (select 1 id,[1,2] arr union all select 2,[])
select id, x from your_table left join unnest(arr) x` vs. `with your_table as (select 1 id,[1,2] arr union all select 2,[])
select id, x from your_table, unnest(arr) x`